# I want to reset the url of same page on selected value change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to reset the url of same page on selected value change something like this

```
selectedvalue.graphic.com
```

---

```
<select id="dynamic-select">
<option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
<option value="City1">Google</option>
<option value="City2">YouTube</option>
<option value="City3">Stack Overflow</option>
```

can any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an onchange event on the select element

```
<select onChange="window.location = '//' + this.value + '.graphic.com';">
<option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
<option value="City1">Google</option>
<option value="City2">YouTube</option>
<option value="City3">Stack Overflow</option>
</select>
```

if you want the browser to open a new window:

```
<select onChange="window.open('//' + this.value + '.graphic.com');">
<option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
<option value="City1">Google</option>
<option value="City2">YouTube</option>
<option value="City3">Stack Overflow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks but i am confused whether i need to create another page or i can do this on the same page.

Comment: I do not understand this comment? If you want the browser to be directed to a new url, this is will do it.

Comment: @Tariq not need to create anther page , if you can use the selected value as part of URL or querystring to load the specific content

Comment: yes it work but the page content does not load. I am working with asp.net ,if you have any solution please..

Comment: You would need to provide more details or else I cannot help further.

Comment: I have a page cityhome.aspx, I want to change url like city1.graphic.com when the selected value in the dropdownlist changed

Comment: I want to load the content of cityHome.aspx content on the dropdownlist selected value change